# Passport API authentication for multiple table

Tags: laravel, api

I'm new to api authentication in laravel. Can we generate token (using passport) for multiple table example.customer table,etc.. in place of users table.I mean when customer is login at that time unique token generate for particular customer and when influencer login at time  token generate for particular influencer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use custom migration

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations
```

And if you want to save token in customer table then

```
$token = $users->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
```

and save it into db.